# Why not returning true even if my condition is verified

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, boolean-expression, function-definition

I'm new to programming and I work on this program.

The requirement is: Write a C program to check a given array (length will be at least 2) of integers and return true if there are two values 15, 15 next to each other.

Although my condition is verified, the function is not returning true unless I exclude the "else". But if I exclude else, it is not returning 0 when false, but any other random number. I don't understand why and how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int check_fifteen(int a[], int size);

int main(){
   int a[]={1, 6, 15, 15, 3, 5, 15};
   int size= sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

   printf( "%d", check_fifteen(a, size));

}
int check_fifteen(int a[], int size){
   int i=0;

   if(size < 2){
       return 0;
   }
   for(i=0; i<size-1; i++){
       if( ( a[i] == 15 ) && ( a[i+1] == 15  ) ){
           return true;
       }
       else
           return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if one pair doesn't satisfy `if condition` you are returning `false`. That shouldn't happen, you should check for all pairs and then return false if none satisfies.

```c
if( ( a[i] == 15 ) && ( a[i+1] == 15  ) ){
           return true;
       }
       else
           return false;
}
```

To

```c
for(i=0; i<size-1; i++){
       if( ( a[i] == 15 ) && ( a[i+1] == 15  ) ){
           return true; // if any pair satisfies you return true there itself
       }
}

// you will reach here only if every pair doesn't satisfy the requirement. 
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop is interrupted as soon as there will be encountered two consecutive elements of the array that either equal each other and to `15` or are not equal.

```
   for(i=0; i<size-1; i++){
       if( ( a[i] == 15 ) && ( a[i+1] == 15  ) ){
           return true;
       }
       else
           return false;
   }
```

At least place the statement `return false` outside the loop.

```
   for(i=0; i<size-1; i++){
       if( ( a[i] == 15 ) && ( a[i+1] == 15  ) ){
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
```

It would be better to declare and define the function the following way

```
int check_fifteen( const int a[], size_t size )
{
    const int Target = 15;
    int success = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; !success && i < size; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] == Target ) success = a[i-1] == Target;
    }

    return success;
}
```

and the variable `size` declare like

```
size_t size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
```

Also there is no great sense to write a function that checks only that two adjacent elements are equal to 15. You could write a more general function.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check_equal_adjacent( const int a[], size_t size, int value )
{
    int success = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; !success && i < size; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] == value ) success = a[i-1] == value;
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 6, 15, 15, 3, 5, 15 };
    size_t size = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    printf( "%s\n", check_equal_adjacent( a, size, 15 ) ? "true" : "false" );
   
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function `check_fifteen` already returns `false` at the first iteration because since the `if` condition isn't satisfied (the first two elements of the pointed array doesn't contain the value `15`), inside of the `else` statement you immediately return `false`.

```
for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
   if ( ( a[i] == 15 ) && ( a[i+1] == 15  ) ){
       return true;
   }
   else
       return false;    // You tell: If the 'if' condition is not matched, return `false`.
}
```

---

Place the `return false;` after the loop, so the `else` statement won't make the function return already at the first iteration when `if ( a[i] == 15  && a[i+1] == 15 )` is not true.

```
for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
   if ( a[i] == 15  && a[i+1] == 15 ) {
       return true;
   }
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of bug is easily avoided if you follow the rule (guideline, stylistic preference) that each function should have only one return point.  Just maintain a flag which is set when you see the validating condition.  Something like:

```
int
check_fifteen(const int *a, int size)
{
        int status = 0;
        const int *b = a + size;
        while( a + 1 < b && !status ) {
                status = a[0] == 15 && a[1] == 15;
                a += 1;
        }
        return status;
}
```

Note that you can reduce the work a bit with a simple "optimization" (bearing in mind that premature optimization is the root of all evil):

```
int
check_fifteen(const int *a, int size)
{
        int status = 0;
        const int *b = a + size;
        while( a + 1 < b && !status ) {
                if( a[1] == 15 ) {
                        status = *a++ == 15;
                } else {
                        a += 2;
                }
        }
        return status;
}
```